# A question on parallel transport of a vector field along a smooth curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, general-relativity

I was given the following exercise:

> Consider the connection on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\Gamma_{1 2}^1 =1$ and all the other $\Gamma_{jk}^i$ equal to zero wrt $(x^1, x^2) = (x,y)$. Determine the equations for parallel transport of a vector field $Y = Y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

I found that the equations of motion would be given by:

$$\frac{dY^1}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt} Y^1 = 0$$

and $$\frac{dY^2}{dt} = 0$$

I can see that the second equations implies that $Y^2$ will be constant, but I can't figure how to solve the first ODE since it contains 2 variables. The solution given to me mentions that the first equation implies that $Y^1 e^y$ is constant, but I don't see why. Furthermore, it states the following:

> The components of the vector field $Y$ along a curve from $C(t_0)$ to $C(t)$ are given by :
> $$  \left[ \begin {array}{c} Y^1 \left( t \right) \\ Y^2
>  \left( t \right) \end {array} \right] 
>  =  \left[ \begin {array}{cc} {{\rm e}^{y \left( t \right) -y \left( {
> \it t_0} \right) }}&0\\ 0&1\end {array} \right] \left[ \begin {array}{c} Y^1 \left( t_0 \right) \\ Y^2
>  \left( t_0 \right) \end {array} \right] 
> $$

Which apparently follows from the first equation. Can some help clarify my confusion about this?

Comment: You sure it is $\frac{dY^1}{dt} +\frac{dy}{dt} Y^{1}=0$ and not $\frac{dY^1}{dt} - \frac{dy}{dt} Y^{1}=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dY^1}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt} Y^1 = 0$$
$$\frac{dY^1}{dt} =- \frac{dy}{dt} Y^{1}$$
$$\int \frac{dY^1}{Y^1} =- \int{dy}$$
$$\ln Y^1=-y+C$$
This gives the final result:
$$Y^1=Ke^{-y}$$
Are you sure it is $\frac{dY^1}{dt} +\frac{dy}{dt} Y^{1}=0$ and not $\frac{dY^1}{dt} - \frac{dy}{dt} Y^{1}=0$ ?

---

Note that this DE:
$$\frac{dY^1}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt} Y^1 = 0$$
Is just:
$$\frac{Y'^1}{Y^1} + y' = 0$$
That you can rewrite as:
$$(\ln Y^1)'+y'=0$$
$$(\ln Y^1+y)'=0$$
Integrate both side.
$$\ln Y^1+y=C$$